# Arguments for date_select in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, actionview

In Rails, there is `date_select` tag.
It has two required arguments: `object_name` and `method`.

I do understand why we need one (as it would serve as an `id`), but can anybody explain, what is the purpose to have two?

Thx!

Answer (score 2):

In `date_select(object_name, method, options = {}, html_options = {})`

`object_name` refers to the instance of the Class whose date attribute you would be setting.

`method` refers to the `attribute` of the object(`object_name`) that you are setting.

For eg:

```
date_select(@post, :posted_on)
```

This would create a date select which when POSTed, would be stored as value of `@post.posted_on`

See [Date Helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select) for details.

Answer (score 2):

`object_name` is the resource name and `method` the attribute name on the resource

For eg:

for `user's date_of_birth`

```
date_select("user", "date_of_birth")
```

Generates a date select that when POSTed is stored in the user variable, in the date_of_birth attribute,

Answer (score 1):

The `object_name` is the object that you'd like to send the date to, while `method` is the attribute you'd like to update with that date. For instance if you're trying to use the date select in your view (using .erb), you'd use:

```
date_select(:article, :publish_date)
```

Check this out for more information about `date_select` and how it works:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#using-date-and-time-form-helpers-model-object-helpers